# App doesn't connect to license service correctly after the update of Android Billing Library to latest 2.0

Tags: android, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have updated Android Billing library to [version 2.0](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes#release-2_0) (released this month).

In addition to minor changes (that is useless to report here) I have edited this line to support the new library version:

```
cl = BillingClient.newBuilder(mActivity).setListener(this).build();
```

in this way:

```
cl = BillingClient.newBuilder(mActivity).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
```

since as stated by release notes `enablePendingPurchases()` is required (and without this App crashes).

In order to get the all Skus to fulfill the removal of methods for Sku hardcoding (honestly I don't how removing them is supposed to improve something), I have tried to query using this code `querySkuDetails()`:

```
SkuDetailsParams.Builder spb = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
cl.querySkuDetailsAsync(spb.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult br, List<SkuDetails> ls) {

    }
});
```

But the `BillingResult` response code is always `5 DEVELOPER_ERROR`if I place the method call in `onBillingClientSetupFinished`.

The previous version has no issue, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something to support the new version properly.

Billing service is able to connect to its backend, but this operation for some reason fails. So seems that error is in the way I use `querySkuDetails()` because `onSkuDetailsResponse` returns always code `5 DEVELOPER ERROR` despite the status code I get in`onBillingSetupFinished` is `OK`.

Answer (score 1):

`-1 SERVICE DISCONNECTED` means `onBillingClientSetupFinished()` had not happened and `.querySkuDetailsAsync()` should run after `onBillingClientSetupFinished()`; if it returns `5 DEVELOPER_ERROR`, the package name or public key might not match and/or the billing service can somehow not be connected.

Comment: The key and all the rest match since as I have said all the others operations work. And onlu `querySkuDetailsAsync` has problem, (and this method is required only with the new version that doesn't allow to use Skus string hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because there already was an IInAppBillingService.aidl in your project. 
Try to removed it and clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs when using `querySkuDetailsAsync(...)`: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Query

The `SkuDetailsParam` that you pass in should also have the list of SKUs and a SkuType (either `SkuType.INAPP` or `SkuType.SUBS`). You are missing these two fields in the sample code you provided.

Sample code from the docs:

```
val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
skuList.add("premium_upgrade")
skuList.add("gas")
val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(SkuType.INAPP)
billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
    // Process the result.
})
```

Also, at this time, Google's GitHub sample project hasn't been updated for Billing v2, but it is still helpful if you want to get both the SkuType.INAPP and SkuType.SUBS: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive_v2/shared-module/src/main/java/com/example/billingmodule/billing/BillingManager.java